# additive persistance ocaml

Tags: math, ocaml

I am having trouble figuring out how to come up with the additive persistence and digital root of an integer For example, the sequence obtained from the starting number 9876 is (9876, 30, 3), so 9876 has an additive persistence of 2 and a digital root of 3.

I converted the integers into a list (i.e {9; 8; 7; 6}), then summed the list to make another integer, and so on recursively until there is only digit left. How can i check to see if only one digit is left? The digital root is this number

Comment: A one-digit non-negative integer is less than 10. That part doesn't seem hard.

Comment: somehow, you must be already doing it in the function which turns a number into a list of digits...

Answer (score 5):

You could just check if your number is less than 10.